# Различия [] и * [C]

Tags: c, синтаксис, c++

Несмотря на то, что с Си я работаю уже довольно давно, я не обращал внимания на возможные различия между двумя способами создания указателей на область памяти. Пример:

```
char * _item1;
char _item2[];
```

Есть ли существенная разница между этими способами?

Comment: Надо начинать с чего нибудь посложнее:
 
    double (*(*f)(double(*)(double)))(double)

Comment: @igumnov, вот за такое надо отрезать руки и отлучать от программирования.

Comment: `char (*(*f)(char(*)(char)))(char)` это

`declare f as pointer to function (pointer to function (char) returning char) returning pointer to function (char) returning char` (cdecl.org в помощь), но вот зачем такое может понадобится - ума не приложу.

Comment: Предлагаю ввести С капчу при попытке ответить на вопрос. Количество плохих ответов уменьшится однозначно.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Да, разница конечно есть.

Код вида

```
char data[];
```

не скомпилируется. Потому что компилятору нужно знать размер массива. Эта форма используется, если размер массива компилятор может вычислить. Например в такой форме

char data[] = "test";

Это равносильно:

char data[5] = "test"; // плюс один символ для концевого нулевого

`char * data` - таким образом объявляется указатель на символ (или строку символов, в зависимости от контекста).

Но дело в том, что в С указатели и массивы очень связаны (если честно, то в С нет массивов - есть только указатели) и всегда важно помнить простую формулу:

```
a[x] равносильно *(a + x)
```

Теперь, встретив в коде что то вида

```
4[a] = 3;
```

Не будете пугаться, а просто поймете, что это

```
a[4] = 3;
```

И для закрепления эффекта вот такой код. Функция `boolToStr` возвращает строку False для нулевого аргумента и True для всех остальных.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char * boolToStr(int i) {
   return "False\0True" + ((i&&1)*6);
}

int main() {
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(0));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(1));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(2));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(3));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(4));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(-1));
   printf("%s\n", boolToStr(-2));

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да уж, спасибо большое, ответ ваш очень обрадовал :)
Вот об этом знал:

         a[x] равносильно *(a + x)

но не был в курсе, что в СИ можно и так поступать:

        4[a] = 3;

Так что, профит =)

Comment: Читал где-то, что первые компиляторы С просто делали замену `a[x] => *(a+x)` сразу при старте компиляции, а потом уже делали все остальное.

Comment: По сути вещей это верно. Наверняка вы бы и без всякого прочтения сами рано или поздно это поняли. Причем массивы таким образом работают во всех языках программирования. В данном случае "a" - некая фиксированная область в памяти, относительно которой высчитывается местоположение в памяти определенного "элемента массива", где "x" - смещение.

Comment: > return "False\0True" + ((i&&1)*6);

А чем этот код лучше очевидного

> return i != 0 ? "True" : "False";

?

Comment: так массивы устроены в С/С++. Это логичная и наиболее простая форма для этого. Но в других языках может быть сделано по другому.

Приведенный код показывает, как можно решить задачу if/тернарного оператора. Приведен исключительно для демонстрации возможности и не агитирую за его использование при каждом возможном случае.

Comment: @Francesco, Вам правильно все рассказали. Есть еще одна мелочь. Вот в таком коде

    f(int a[], int *b) { a = b; b = a; }

или даже

    f(int a[10], int *b) { ... }

разницы в использовании (записи) `a` и `b` нет никакой (они параметры). Обе переменные можно одинаково индексировать и использовать как результат в операторе присваивания.

Реально в стеке вызова f() будет каждая из них будет представлена указателем на `int`.

Comment: @Francesco, "Причем массивы таким образом работают во всех языках программирования" -- как минимум для PHP это не так.

Comment: > Приведен исключительно для демонстрации возможности (...)

Да, все ок. Надо мне таки читать ответы полностью :)

Answer (score 7):

Различий, если честно, довольно много. Массив *содержит* символы, указатель же лишь *указывает* на них. В этом базовое отличие, из которого вытекают все остальные.

Рассмотрим объявление переменных:

```
char* p = "ЖЖЖ";
char q[] = "ЖЖЖ";
```

**Инициализация**:

В нашем объявлении `p` -- указатель на глобально аллоцированную константную строку "ЖЖЖ\0". Поскольку `p` указывает на литерал, значения, полученные при разыменовании `p` доступны только для чтения, и `*p = 'В'` -- представляет собой undefined behaviour (на многих архитектурах так сразу access violation).

`q` же указывает на массив данных из 4-ёх элементов `'Ж'`, `'Ж'`, `'Ж'`, `'\0'`, доступный и для записи, известного при компиляции размера, и аллоцированный в текущем scope. Это, в частности, означает, что возвращать значение `q` за пределы текущей функции нельзя. Физическое размещение данных такое же, как и в строке -- в частности, поэтому массив можно использовать как строку.

Кроме того (это уже замечено в других ответах), для `q` вы *не можете* опустить инициализацию, в отличие от объявления `p`. Если вы указываете размер массива *явно*, количество элементов в инициализаторе может быть меньше, чем требуется.

**Изменяемость**:

В отличие от `p`, `q` является *константой* -- компилятор не даст переприсвоить его значение. Значение же `p` можно свободно менять по ходу программы.

**Размер**: (подмечено в комментариях)

Оператор `sizeof` для массива возвращает размер массива -- количество байт в нём. Оператор `sizeof` для указателя возвращает, разумеется, размер указателя в памяти, который никак не связан с размером строки, лежащей по этому указателю. Заметьте, что `strlen` не обязательно возвратит вам размер массива:

```
char oops[] = "Lala\0fa"; // strlen(oops) == 4
```

**Конверсии**:

В большинстве контекстов, если ожидается `char*`, переменная типа `char[N]` будет автоматически приведена к ожидаемому типу, и её значением будет указатель на первый элемент массива (исключения: `sizeof`, `&`). Переменные же типа `char*` не приводятся к типу `char[N]`.

Исключение: формальные параметры функций. Для них `char*` и `char[]` практически одно и то же.

**Передача параметров**:

В языке C параметры-массивы передаются *по ссылке*, указатели (да и все другие типы аргументов) -- *по значению*. Это сделано специально, чтобы указатель на массив и массив вели себя одинаково.

Вот источник информации: [Arrays and Pointers/C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: Отличный обзор.

Могу лишь добавить, что 

если используется кодировка utf-8, то "ЖЖЖ" займет 7 байтов и

если написать 

    stаtic q[] = "ЖЖЖ";

то q можно (насколько хорошо/безопасно - другой вопрос) возвращать из функции, а память, инициализированную символами ЖЖЖ изменять.

Comment: @avp: спасибо! Трюк со `static` хорош, в конце-концов, синглтон Майерса [именно так](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1661529/276994) и сделан. (Конечно, остаётся проблема с одновременным доступом, но это уже совсем другая история.)

Comment: @avp: кстати, да, размер строки зависит от кодировки. Для однозначного результата нужна латиница или ANSI-кодировка (с MSVC). Или не знаю что с gcc.

Comment: @VladD, насколько я понимаю gcc вообще не смотрит на кодировку. Какие байты набили в редакторе, такие и будут в строке.

А про lock (одновременный доступ), я думаю, вопросы еще будут.

Comment: >Изменяемость:
>
>В отличие от p, q является константой -- компилятор не даст переприсвоить его значение. Значение же q можно свободно менять по ходу программы.

@VladD, Вы немогли бы объяснить эту строчку? Имеется в виду то, что у q можно поменять значения ( Ж на Ъ, например ), но q не может указывать на другую область памяти?

Comment: @LoOny: Ой, это у меня опечатка, там должно быть `p` во второй раз. Имеется в виду, что код наподобие `q = p;` просто не скомпилируется. Спасибо за замечание, сейчас исправлю!

---
Значения _элементов_ массива можно всегда поменять, а указатель указывает на то, на что указывает -- поменять-то компилятор даст, но это может быть и не разрешено, как в случае инициализации литералом.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо, теперь всё встало на свои места. Присоединяюсь к @avp - отличный обзор.

Answer (score 5):

Различаться они будут *типом* (К.О.) со всеми вытекающими:

1) адресная арифметика

```
   int a[3] = {1,2,3};
   int *pa = a;

   cout <<&a[0]<<endl;  //адрес первого элемента массива
   cout <<pa<<endl; //тоже самое
   cout <<&a<<endl; //адрес массива, он же адрес первого элемента

   cout <<&a[0]+1<<endl; //адрес второго элемента
   cout <<pa+1<<endl; //тоже самое
   cout <<&a+1<<endl; //магия тут
```

но при передаче в функцию массив уже становиться указателем, то есть передать массив в функцию нельзя

```
void f(int* a)
{
    cout <<&a<<endl;
    cout <<&a+1<<endl;
}
```

2) генерируемый код

```
a[0] = 13;
pa[0] = 13;
```

сгенерируемые инструкции для каждого присваивания могут быть различны

3) расположение данных

```
{
    ...
    int a[3] = {1,2,3}; //будет расположен на стеке, в текуйщей области видимости
    ...
}

int arr[2] = {4,2};
...
{
    ...
    int* pArr = arr; //просто скопирует адрес
    ...
}
```

также при динамическом выделении нужно использовать delete [],вместо delete, чтобы компилятор корректно интерпретировал область памяти

```
struct bar
{
   bar()
   {
      cout <<"bar ctor"<<endl;   
   }

  ~bar()
  {
     cout <<"bar dtor"<<endl;
  }
};

bar* da = new bar[3];

//delete da; //выведет bar dtor только 1 раз
delete [] da; //вызовет нужное количество деструкторов
```

4) шаблоны
различие в типах можно продемострировать специализацией шаблонов

```
template<class T>
void foo()
{
  cout <<"other"<<endl; 
}

template<>
void foo<int*>()
{
  cout <<"pointer"<<endl;       
}

template<>
void foo<int[]>()
{
  cout <<"array"<<endl;       
}

foo<int*>();
foo<int[]>();
foo<short>();
```

[Код](http://liveworkspace.org/code/32lKXi$0)

Comment: Суть не забыл, очевидно что
    cout <<sizeof(a)<<endl;
    cout <<sizeof(pa)<<endl;
будут различны тоже